# magento custom module - how to remove top menu in custom module at specific class

Tags: magento

I have a module name ModuleA in adminhtml including many classes(classA, classB, classC ...)

I just want to remove the top menu in classC's block.

I already remove the default header and footer.

but I don't know how to remove the top menu in adminpanel.

Would you plz teach me how to hide or remove the top menu? 
!important : it takes just speicific class!

Comment: This is kind of unclear. Post some code or at least some screenshots.

Comment: I solved this problem by using jquery.hide() or jquery.remove() method